# Does file on S3 loads on browser through EC2 when EC2 requests that file

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a PDF file in an S3 bucket which I load in the browser through a JS script (`pdf.js`). The JavaScript file is served by a PHP script running on an EC2 instance.

When I visit `http://mysite/example.php`, the `pdf.js` script gets loaded and then the PDF file also loaded in the browser.

Does the browser download the PDF file directly from S3 or from the EC2 instance?

**Note**: The JavaScript script loads the PDF from a URL like

`https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/{bucket_name}/file.pdf`.

Comment: Is your JavaScript requesting the file or your PHP code? If JavaScript, directly from S3, otherwise routed through EC2.

Comment: Thanks Robby for your quick response. S3 file's path is included in JS file and that JS file is loaded in PHP file. That JS file is PDF.JS which loads PDF file in the browser itself. When I run PHP script it loads PDF.JS which is having absolute path of PDF file on S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your PHP script is loading the file from S3 (i.e., the execution is being carried out *on the EC2 instance*) and serving it to the client as part of the response, then it passes through EC2.

Otherwise, if your PHP script is just loading the JS that serves the S3 object to the client to download in browser, then the execution is being done *on the client* and the file is being retrieved from S3 directly by the client without passing through EC2.

In all cases, you should note that data transfer fees from S3 to EC2 within the **SAME REGION** is free. See [S3 Data Transfer Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/).

Comment: Hello Khalid, Thanks for your help. **I have updated my question again** so that you can understand what exactly what the scenario is. **I need some more help from you**. I am running PHP script but the file from S3 bucket is loaded through JS. So I am little bit confused here.

Comment: A JS client-side script gets executed on the client. The PHP server-side script just loads the JS content for the client to download locally for execution, i.e., the client is the one that is downloading the S3 object. See my updated answer.

Comment: **Thank you Khalid**.Thanks for your response and help. Now I can consider that PDF file is not loading through EC2 for this scenario.